# Remove digital signature from generated RCP's exe

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, tycho

We are facing a problem in the generated RCP using Tycho Maven build (Tycho version 1.6.0), where the generated exe is digitally signed by Eclipse. Until now we were using Eclipse 4.8 where the exe was not signed by Eclipse. Recently we have migrated to Eclipse 4.14, where we face this issue. This is a blocker for us as we sign the exe using our signature. But now since Eclipse signs it, we are not able to add our signature.

Is there a way to generate the product without the exe being signed by Eclipse ?

Or is there any property that I could configure in pom.xml, so that the signing step will be skipped ?

I also went through the below threads where it is mentioned only recently Eclipse has started signing exes. I was not able to find a solution from there.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548431

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548893

Any help here would be really great. Thank you.

[image: Eclipse's signature in the exe]

Comment: Eclipse 4.14 is two releases behind and Tycho 1.6 is outdated as well. If you can reproduce the issue in the current version, tell what exactly the problem is. Both, mentioned bug reports are about other things. The first is about that the `eclipse.exe` (not the RCP `.exe` that will be created) should be signed. The second is about that Tycho should provide the possibility to sign the executable.

Comment: Hello Howlger, Thanks for your reply & clarification. In our organization, we are bound to use Eclipse 4.14, Tycho 1.6 & Java 1.8. But, I tried generating a product with Eclipse 4.15 & 4.16 (by clicking on Export an Eclipse product in Product Configuration Editor in IDE). Even there the generated RCP's exe was signed by Eclipse. My exact problem is, the generated product's exe, example: MyProduct.exe has signatures in it, which has to be removed. Any suggestion would be of great help. Thank you.